# Synchronize drawRect for ViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a view controller class that parses a clip's frames and renders it into an NSOpenGLView. Problem is, the frames being rendered are choppy as it seems the view controller is telling the view to draw faster than it could handle. See code snippet below for reference:

```
// Snippet code from view controller
- (void) tellViewToDrawWithFrameAtTimeInterval:(float)timeVal
{
    _myGlobalTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:timeVal
                                                  target:self                                  
                                selector:@selector(triggerRenderAtTime)
                                userInfo:nil
                                 repeats:YES];

}

- (void) triggerRenderAtTime
{
    [_myView setPixelData:[_myPixelBuffer objectAtIndex:_frameIndex];
    [_myView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

    _frameIndex++;
}

// The NSTimer object is eventually killed elsewhere in the class' implementation
```

I even tried to set the timer to call at intervals of 3, 5, 10 seconds just to ensure the view has time to process everything and render the frame. However, the results observed was still the same - the view is still skipping frames that it should be drawing. I'm currently looking at CVDisplayLink, but I'm very unfamiliar as to what they do yet, and based on what I've read so far, it seems to be a complex solution on an otherwise simple problem (*I think...*). Can anyone shed some light to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out, and I had to eliminate drawRect completely and use CVDisplayLink for my drawing. Apple's guide was perfect for this:

[Technical Q&A QA1385 - Driving OpenGL Rendering Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1385/_index.html)